# How to define a Recurrent Convolutional network layer in CNTK?

Tags: python, cntk, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to CNTK, and using its awesome python API.  I have problem figuring out how I may define a Recurrent Convolutional network layer since the Recurrence() seems to assume a regular network layer only.

Be more specific, I would like to have recurrence among convolutional layers.

Any pointer or even a simple example would be highly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this in a meaningful way (i.e. without destroying the structure of natural images that convolutions rely on). The simplest is to just have an LSTM at the final layer i.e.

```
convnet = C.layers.Sequential([Convolution(...), MaxPooling(...), Convolution(...), ...])
z = C.layers.Sequential([convnet, C.layers.Recurrence(LSTM(100)), C.layers.Dense(10)])
```

for a 10-class problem.

The more complex way would be to define your own recurrent cell that only uses convolutions and thus respects the structure of natural images. To define a recurrent cell you need to write a function that takes the previous state and an input (i.e. a single frame if you are processing video) and outputs the next state and output. For example you can look into [the implementation of the GRU in the CNTK layers module](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/5643a5619097b125f49e629f5bdbbc5a6ceedcf0/bindings/python/cntk/layers/blocks.py#L299-L336), and adapt it to use `convolution` instead of `times` everywhere. If this is what you want I can try to provide such an example. However, I encourage you to try the simple way first.

**Update**: I wrote a barebones convolutional GRU. You need to pay special attention to how the initial state is defined but otherwise it seems to work fine. Here's the layer definition

```
def ConvolutionalGRU(kernel_shape, outputs, activation=C.tanh, init=C.glorot_uniform(), init_bias=0, name=''):
    conv_filter_shape = (outputs, C.InferredDimension) + kernel_shape
    bias_shape = (outputs,1,1)
    # parameters
    bz = C.Parameter(bias_shape, init=init_bias, name='bz')  # bias
    br = C.Parameter(bias_shape, init=init_bias, name='br')  # bias
    bh = C.Parameter(bias_shape, init=init_bias, name='bc')  # bias
    Wz = C.Parameter(conv_filter_shape, init=init, name='Wz') # input
    Wr = C.Parameter(conv_filter_shape, init=init, name='Wr') # input
    Uz = C.Parameter(conv_filter_shape, init=init, name='Uz') # hidden-to-hidden
    Ur = C.Parameter(conv_filter_shape, init=init, name='Hz') # hidden-to-hidden
    Wh = C.Parameter(conv_filter_shape, init=init, name='Wc') # input
    Uh = C.Parameter(conv_filter_shape, init=init, name='Hc') # hidden-to-hidden
    # Convolutional GRU model function
    def conv_gru(dh, x):
        zt = C.sigmoid (bz + C.convolution(Wz, x) + C.convolution(Uz, dh))        # update gate z(t)
        rt = C.sigmoid (br + C.convolution(Wr, x) + C.convolution(Ur, dh))        # reset gate r(t)
        rs = dh * rt                                                            # hidden state after reset
        ht = zt * dh + (1-zt) * activation(bh + C.convolution(Wh, x) + C.convolution(Uh, rs))
        return ht
    return conv_gru
```

and here is how to use it

```
x = C.sequence.input_variable(3,224,224))
z = C.layers.Recurrence(ConvolutionalGRU((3,3), 32), initial_state=C.constant(0, (32,224,224)))
y = z(x)
x0 = np.random.randn(16,3,224,224).astype('f') # a single seq. with 16 random "frames"
output = y.eval({x:x0}) 
output[0].shape
(16, 32, 224, 224)
```

Comment: Thank you Nikos.  Yes, the second case is what I am looking for, i.e. recurrent cells which use solely convolution, and a simple example would be great and much appreciated.  At the moment, I will look into the GRU example you have suggested.  Concerning training, is there anything I should pay attention to ?  e.g. BPTT details and memory issues.

Comment: I updated the answer with an actual convolutional GRU.

Comment: Thank you so much, Nikos, this is a very clear example of step function, and I really appreciate it.